# Where can cash reserves be stored in Canada, with 100% protection of principal and higher interest than high-rate savings accounts?

Tags: canada, savings

I abbreviate 'the amount of reserves to be deposited' to 'principal.'

**Criteria:**

1. This principal must be conserved (excepting rarities like the
   collapse of Canada)
2. Must be able to be withdrawn no longer than a month after requesting
   a withdrawal.

*Investing For Canadians For Dummies, 3 Ed* ((2009) by Tony Martin, Eric Tyson) recommends [high-rate savings accounts](https://www.ratesupermarket.ca/bank_accounts/results?location=Downtown%2C+Toronto%2C+ON%2C+Canada&province_id=5&lat=43.654262&lng=-79.38597500000003&level=neighborhood&display_locale=Downtown&type=savings&deposit=50000) which appear to yield the highest interest (up to 1.75% and 1.50%), and so which transcend their other recommendation of 'money market mutual funds'.

Are high-rate savings accounts truly the option with the highest interest?

Comment: Do you mean, "the option with the highest interest and 100% protection of principal"? Are you looking to protect $100,000 or less? Are you willing to lock your money up for a longer time period and receive NO interest if you withdraw early, but the full interest if you leave it for the full time period?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton `the option with the highest interest and 100% protection of principal` : Yes. Regarding the amount, the amount doesn't matter; I think that you are implying CDIC protection? `Are you willing to lock your money up for a longer time period and receive NO interest if you withdraw early, but the full interest if you leave it for the full time period?` : Yes, please discuss this. Are you implying redeemable GICs?